# performance between glDrawTexfOES and vertex buffer objects

Tags: performance, opengl-es

I am coding an open gl graphics engine and am wondering about the performance of glDrawTexfOES(1) vs vertex buffer object as billboards(2). I know (1) is faster than (2) but you cannot rotate (1). So if i need rotation i must use (2) and i now do not know if i should allow using (1) as game objects apart from backgroundimages because if i use both there will be alot of state changes for the GPU which is not very performant

so the question is :
 is the performance gain of (1) over (2) more than the performance lost by changing states between each (1) draw and (2) draw

cheers, aerlfredith